# How do I open old Android SDK samples in Android Studio 1.1 without changing the build files?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I attempt to open the Android SDK samples for v19, for example `connectivity/BasicNetworking`, I get the following error in Android Studio:

```
The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.12.2). 
The recommended version is 1.1.0
```

Not only can I not build the project - I can't even open it and browse the source code.

I understand I can alter build.gradle to use v1.1.0 of the plugin but I don't feel that should be my job. Google is providing both the samples and the IDE. Why can't I open their samples in their IDE?

Is there any setting in Android Studio I can set so that it automatially sets the latest gradle plugin version in the `build.gradle` file when opening old projects?

Comment: I doubt there's anything you can do except of modifying the build file manually.. I think it's worth filing an issue so that they could address this problem in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The "Import an Android code sample" on the Android Studio startup screen, or "File > Import sample" actually takes care of this (although a side effect is that it copies the project to a new folder).

Comment: Yes, the trick is to close all open projects, otherwise you cannot see the "File -> Import sample"